# Powershell ForEach Loop Failing

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-5.0, mdt

I'm trying to generate a report for all WIM files in my MDT Deployment Share.  Basically, I think need to do a `ForEach` loop on all the WIM files found.  I have what I think should work but, obviously, it doesn't.  How far off am I?

```
$WimPath = "G:\DeploymentShare\Operating Systems"

Get-ChildItem -Path $WimPath -Filter *.wim -Recurse -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo | Select-Object FileName | ForEach-Object { Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath $_ }
```

The error I'm seeing is nagging about the Parameter being incorrect for the `Get-WindowsImage` command.

```
Get-WindowsImage : The parameter is incorrect.
At line:3 char:147
+ ... t-Object FileName | ForEach-Object { Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath $_ }
+                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm thinking my `Select-Object` isn't working like I think it should or I'm not using the pipeline correctly in my `Get-WindowsImage` command.

Comment: try `Get-ChildItem -Path $WimPath -Filter *.wim -Recurse -File  | ForEach-Object { Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath $_.fullname }`

Comment: @Brendand62269, well done!  I was wondering if I even needed the `Select-Object` at all.  I guess I didn't...  How do I mark you as the one who answered it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a PowerShell noob and don't fully understand this, but I *think* what is going on can be explained by first focusing on this part of the command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $WimPath -Filter *.wim -Recurse -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo | Select-Object FileName
```

To get this far, we first get all the `*.wim` files in your path, we expand the VersionInfo property, and then select the FileName. In the console, that will show you results like this:

```
FileName
--------
[files here]
```

The trick is in understanding what PowerShell is telling you with this output. The fact you see a `FileName` header means the pipeline has a stream of *Objects* with one property named `FileName`. Then we send that stream of Objects to `ForEach-Object` and look at the `$_` special variable.

Hopefully it is clearer now what is going on. `Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath $_` wants to see a string value holding the path of a *.wim file. But we sent it an object with one property.

You can fix this a few ways... adding `ExpandProperty` to the second `Select-Object` would probably do it. But really there's no reason for two `Select-Object`s in there at all. I think you could just do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $WimPath -Filter *.wim -Recurse -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | ForEach-Object { Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath $_ }
```

And the trick here is the string representation you see in the shell from `Get-ChildItem` doesn't necessarily show every property in the object. There wouldn't be space. The FileName was always there, and you can see it by checking the `Get-Member` cmdlet, like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $WimPath -Filter *.wim -Recurse -File | Get-Member
```

Comment: Like you, I'm a bit of a _noob_.  Good catch on the **string** value needed for the `Get-WindowsImage` command.  Now that I look at it, the documentation states that's exactly what's needed.   I was messing with `Get-ChildItem -Path $WimPath -Filter *.wim -Recurse -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo | Select-Object FileName` and _thought_ it was giving me what I needed.  I didn't fully understand what type of data it was giving me and I still don't fully understand how to figure it out.